# Dynamically adding columns to middle of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where columns need to be dynamically added or removed within the middle of the table (using JavaScript/jQuery).

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <!-- INSERT COLUMN(S) HERE -->
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <!-- INSERT COLUMN(S) HERE -->
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The idea is that I want to expand or contract the table as necessary dynamically. The way I have prepared things is to replace `<!-- INSERT COLUMN(S) HERE -->` with a tag with an ID, e.g. `<span id="newcols"></span>` and then use `$('#newcols').html('<td>abc</td>');` to insert the columns and `$('#newcols').html('');` to remove them.

However `<span>` is not working, and FireFox bumps it to above the `<table>` tag in the DOM. Is there a semantically-valid tag I can use to acheive this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use td instead of span, give it a newcols class, and with css put .newcols as display:none, then you replace content as needed and show the column

Comment: Thanks for that, but the trouble is that the number of columns is unknown and is dynamically generated. It could be 1, but it could be 5.

Comment: And how do you know where you need to insert them

Comment: The insertion point is fixed (the columns before and after the insertion are not added/removed)

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/yrpz8mea/1/

Comment: Wow - thanks! Almost there - what if I wanted to remove the newly added columns and then add a whole set of new ones (quantity unknown) in their place within the same session?

Comment: Ok an answer below along with your solution here set me on the right track. I know how to solve this now. Will update in a bit! thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

If you already know middle column number then you can use following jquery code.

```
$( "table tr td:nth-child(2)").after('<td>new cell added</td>');

                       OR 

$("#table1").find('td').eq(<column-number>).after('<td>new cell added</td>');
```

**Option 2:**

HTML:

```
 <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td class="thirdCol"><!--value here --></td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
      </tr>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".thirdCol").html("new dataadded");
```

There are many more ways too. Let us know if you still didn't find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using toggle() http://api.jquery.com/toggle/, here is my example in **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/8th60nxf/)**

**JS**

```
$('#toggleCol').click(function() {
  $('.newcols').toggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td class='newcols' style='display:none'>Col hidden show</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td class='newcols' style='display:none'>Col hidden show</td>
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type='button' id='toggleCol' value='toggle me' />
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td class='insertionPoint'>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td class='insertionPoint'>Jill</td>
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
// to insert
$(".insertionPoint").after("<td class='insertedColumns'>abc</td>");

// to remove
$(".insertedColumns").remove();
```

Comment: Okay, this is not exactly what I needed, but you set me on the right track. Thanks a lot!